# Mixed result from MySQL Query, How to sort

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am querying a table called request that looks like this

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+    
| message_id | client_id | admin_id | message | date_posted | read_status |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And as admin needs to get all the messages that are not read (read_status = 0) but I don't know how to get the result and display them into different tabs example

```
Client 44
Hi Sir
```

then a different section (div)

```
Client 87
Give me the number
```

So messages from the same client are put together and inserted into its own div 
The thing is the same client can have multiple rows with different messages. Oh and for each row selected I want update the read_status to 1 so it doesn't get selected later on. **Any help is much appreciated!**

**PS** I'm using PDO to query with prepared statements to keep things clean!

Comment: we want to help, but you can't expect us to write code for you, show some effort.

Comment: I'm ready to do it code wise... But I don't understand the concept of organizing the data :(

Comment: I had this thought of organizing into a 2D array for example for id 44 has these messages and id 88 has these messages.. But I'm afraid its gonna get messy and hard to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a `<div`> for each client, where that `<div>` contains all unread messages for the client that `<div>` belongs to.

That would mean you need to group your results by client. There are two ways you could do that:

1. Let MySQL sort the messages, and let PHP keep track of when the `client_id` changes so you can close the previous `<div>` and open a new one for the new client;
2. Group the messages using PHP after fetching the messages, then loop through that.

For the first option, you could do something like this:

```
$current_client_id = 0;

foreach ($conn->query("SELECT ... ORDER BY `client_id` ASC") as $message) {
    if ($message['client_id'] != $current_client_id) {
        if ($current_client_id > 0) {
            // if it's 0, there is no <div> to close yet
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>Messages for client #' . $message['client_id'] . '</p>';
        $current_client_id = $message['client_id'];
    }

    echo 'message details here';
}

if ($current_client_id > 0) {
    // if it's not 0, there were messages so you need to
    // close the last client's <div>
    echo '</div>';
}
```

For the second option, you could do something like this:

```
$grouped_messages = array();

foreach ($conn->query("SELECT ...") as $message) {
    $client_id = $message['client_id'];

    if (!isset($grouped_messages[$client_id])) {
        $grouped_messages[$client_id] = array();
    }

    $grouped_messages[$client_id][] = $message;
}

foreach ($grouped_messages as $client_id => $client_messages) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<p>Messages for client #' . $client_id . '</p>';

    foreach ($client_messages as $message) {
        echo 'message details here';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

The first option is more efficient, because you're only looping once. But in my personal opinion, the second option delivers cleaner, easier to read and understand code, so I'd prefer that if you're not dealing with a large number of messages, or if you're passing the array of messages to a separate view layer or template.

You'll have to fill in the query yourself, I don't know if you want to fetch all fields or only a few of them, sort it by `date_posted`, filter only messages with a certain `admin_id` or join the `request` table with another table for example.

I also didn't use a prepared statement, but you can replace the loops on `$conn->query()` with one quite easily:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ...");
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $message) {
```

As long as you're not binding any parameters, `PDO::query()` is basically shorthand for exactly that.

Comment: Oh, I forgot: inside the `foreach` where you're echo'ing the message details, you could execute an `UPDATE` query on the `message_id` to set `read_status` to 1, or you could build an array of all `message_id`s that you're showing and execute a single bulk `UPDATE` query (more efficient).

Comment: Wow! That is extremely helpful and it makes a lot of sense! I'm gonna go with option 2 since I understood the code more and easier to expand for more operations. Thanks alot!

Comment: After trying out the code there was a problem with the result where the grouped messages array contains arrays that have the same data as key value pair and index value pair like this:
array (size=12)
  'message_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'client_id' => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => string '6' (length=1)
  'admin_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
as you can see there is 'client_id' = 6 and index 1 = 6 which are the same thing

Comment: That's because you haven't set the fetch mode, and PDO defaults to a fetch mode of `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which returns the array you saw. If you **only** want the numeric keys, set it to `PDO::FETCH_NUM` or if you **only** want the strings, set it to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. See http://php.net/pdo_setattribute for how to set the default fetch mode.